# .NET Data Provider for Teradata 1150009 Message truncation error, not all data was received

Tags: teradata, provider

I get this error message whenever i try to establish a connection to Teradata server using Teradata client provider 13.10.

[.NET Data Provider for Teradata[1150009] Message truncation error, not all data was received.

Please advise me to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

This is a socket related error from the .Net Provider. The Database or operating system has likely closed the socket connection. Can you complete a traceroute to the server or a telnet to port 1025 of the server's IP address?

Comment: This error does not occur all the time. it occurs once in a blue moon. i tried telnet it is reaching the port without any issue. could you please tell any obstacle that block the port in any reason

Comment: An intermittent error like this may be best addressed with the involvement of your network team as well. This is a communication error between the Teradata server and the client.